# EmberJS, Helper with an "as" block

Tags: ember.js, decorator, helper

I have an Object and then I have a Decorator that consumes the Object and returns a Human-friendly representation of the Object.

For example:

```
object = { id: "XXX1", detail: "XXX2" }
decoratedObject { title: "The Red Building", detail: "Has 101 stories" }
```

I would like to use the Decorator in a template:

```
{{#decorator-helper object as |decoratedObject|}}
  <h1>{{decoratedObject.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{decoratedObject.detail}}</p>
{{/decorator-helper}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a component for this.

Generally you should use helpers if you want to use them to calculate other values like this:

```
{{my-component value=(my-helper val)}}
```

If you want to use block syntax you should use a component.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do this with helpers. Why don't you define a computed property called `decoratedObject` on your controller or component that would be based on object ?

```
decoratedObject: Ember.computed('object', {
    get() {
      // Build your decorated object and return it
      return decoratedObject;
    }
})
```

This would make your decorated object available in your template and dynamically rebuild it when object changes.